# Twitter bootstrap Modal - Remove Previous States and start afresh

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So this is my modal

```
                                                                                                              <div class="modal hide fade" >
<div class="modal-header">
    Some Content
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center;">
            <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#a_c" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#b_c" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="a_c">
                AC
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="b_c">                
                BC
                    </div>
        </div> <!-- /tabbable --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

When I choose the tab B, close the modal and select the modal again - The state persists with B. I want the modal to start afresh as it would do the first time, with A

Comment: Where is your function calling the modal ? ( I mean the function to open the modal) :)

Answer (score 0):

try with 
    `$('#myModal').modal();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');`

when you press tab B

Comment: also make tab B visible `$('#myTab a[href="#b_c"]').tab('show');`

Comment: U interpreted my question, wrong.

Consider: a form is filled in the modal (without submitting) and the modal is closed.

When the modal is opened again, it does not start fresh, it opens with the incomplete form. I want the form to be new.

Comment: ok. i miss interpreted. When you load modalbox initialize the tab `$('#loadModalboxLink').click(function(){ $('#myTab a:first').tab('show'); });`

Comment: `#myTab` - give an `id` for your tab `<ul>` and `#loadModalboxLink` is the id of the link which loads the modalbox on click